# Change default registration behavior in Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

We have recently switched to Keycloak to handle the login to our website.
It's still possible to register and Keycloak has a user registration page, but I basically need to change the definition of 'registrating'.
By default it means "insert a new user in the DB with the info given by the user through the registration form". But that's not what we want, we already have all the users that CAN register in our DB, and registrating as a user pretty much means updating a record in our DB.

I have already made changes to the a few classes and redeployed them by packaging them and then adding the Jar to the *\deployments* directory. But I can't seem to find the classes that I have to change to get the registration page to behave the way I want.

How can I change the default behavior of the registration page? What classes do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

I've never do this, but i'd take a look to the user store SPI and authenticator SPI.
I suggest you in writing directly in the Keycloak discourse forum (https://keycloak.discourse.group/) . They will surely give you a hand.

PS: with SPI you'll add features to Keycloak, but in your case i think that you'll need also to change the GUI. See Keycloak Themes in the official doc.

Comment: I have already made quite alot of changes to the ui and several .ftl (freemarker) pages. But now i'm looking at the backend, that's where I get stuck atm.